# When does OnNewToken() actually get called?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I've looked over the documentation, and it states that OnNewToken() will get called when a new token is generated. Typically this will be on app install, restores, or if a user clears their data. There's also times, although rare, that the token will just be invalidated and a new token will be issued.

It's the last case that I'm most curious about.

If a user is using the application, and their token becomes invalid, is OnNewToken() called then, or will it just be called the next time the application starts? In my testing I haven't been able to get OnNewToken() to be called while the application *is in use*. I've started the application on a fresh install, retrieved the token via OnNewToken() and then deleted the user's token separately outside of that method, and OnNewToken() is not called until I stop the application and start it again.

It's fine if that's how it works. I'm just trying to figure out if I need to account for on the fly token changes while a user is running the application.

Also, a second and slightly related question, is it bad practice to check a user's FCM token when they log in to make sure they have the latest token?

Comment: "check a user's FCM token" What does that mean in code?

Comment: By calling FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you manager a token registry yourself, you typically check and send an updated token to the registry/server in two places:

1. In the main method or first activity of your app by calling `FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken()`, to ensure you have the latest token for that user when the app starts.
2. In the `onNewToken` on your service, to ensure you have the latest token for that user when the service is active.

So on your second question: it is indeed quite common to call `FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken()` in the main method or first activity.

Comment: OK. This is the direction I was planning on heading, but I've been getting conflicting information on whether or not it was necessary. Some suggest that OnNewToken() is enough, but my observations would definitely lead me to believe I should have a redundant check on login. We've been running into expired token issues.

I'm also considering calling GetToken() after login instead of in the MainActivity. We have multiple users on the same device, so this would allow us to make sure each user has the latest token on shift change. I'm assuming this would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `OnNewToken` would be called on the fly if the old one was invalidated. You shouldn't need to manually check the token when they log in.

Comment: Well, it was my understanding that I wouldn't need to check a token manually when a user logs in as well, but in practice I can't say that's been my observation. I have definitely been having issues with tokens changing and not being aware that it's changed. A Firebase help ticket I had did ultimately conclude with "redundancy/checking user tokens manually isn't unheard of", but I'm still trying to figure out the best way to handle this.

Comment: If I check a user's token on login, in theory, I don't even need code in OnNewToken() unless the token can change while a user is running the application, but thus far I've been unable to make that happen (even when I delete their token myself, presumably forcing a new one to be issued).